# `RxJs` - how to wait untill `Iframe` contents loaded and trigger an function?

Tags: iframe, rxjs, rxjs5

I am a absolute beginner to `Rxjs` - But I came to know that, It works better for `async' operations.

In my web page, there is a `iframe` loading the content ( it has some loop in it )

once all done, I would like to trigger a event to say that, "hey all contents are loaded in iframe" - how to do this using `rxjs`?

i see that some example like this:

```
function initialize() {
    // Do something on initialization
}

Rx.DOM.ready().subscribe(initialize);
```

But actually what is the correct way to write the function and wait until the iframe contents loads?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why your code doesn't work and it turned out this is probably a bug in RxJS-DOM. See [Rx.DOM.ready() seems to not work](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/issues/106).